# Visual Studio 2012 Solution Explorer Search doesn't search cshtml files

Tags: search, razor, refactoring

When I refactored a namespace in Visual Studio 2012 MVC 4 Web project, the razor files that included the "@model MyFirstWeb.Domains.LoginModel" did not get touched which caused an exception when compiling for first use.

It isn't that much of a deal but rather odd?, can I register the cshtml as a file extension to search?

If I use the "Search Solution Explorer" to try and file the text I know exists in that file I get nothing?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post that explains the ins and outs of the Solution Explorer Search:

http://www.schwammysays.net/visual-studio-2012-tip-search-in-solution-explorer

Basically, you're searching the Solution Explorer, not the files, so anything that's visible in the Solution Explorer will be searched.  Luckily, the Solution Explorer now includes logical structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known bug in VS 2013 R1, which was identified and then closed but users are still having issues.  Although outside of the solution explorer, you can use the 'Ctrl + ,' search to these filetypes in your solution.

The related tickets are here....

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801838/solution-explorer-search-doesnt-include-js-or-cshtml-results

and

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801836/solution-explorer-doesnt-search-files-projects-inside-solution-folders